# Revo Scale R rxCube and other open source parallel package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, revolution-r

I have a 72 million observation data frame. It has two columns, `my_id` and `my_rand` variables.
The data frame has about 6 million unique `my_id`. I need to calculate average `my_rank` value by `my_id` (group by `my_id`).
I tried to run the above regular R command, however it seems freeze the R (maybe data too big to fit memory).

```
avg_rank_by_id<-aggregate(dataframe1["my_rank"],by=dataframe1["my_id"], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Is there a way to run Revo Scale R such as `rxCube` etc. to achieve the goal? I am running on Linux. It tried below, but got error.

I am new to R. Besides Revo Scale R, is there another high performance computing open source R package available? Thanks.

```
acct_avg_rank <- rxCube( N(m13_rank)~acct_id, data=payee_merge, means=TRUE, returnDataFrame=TRUE)
```

All independent variables must be factors for `rxCube` and `rxCrossTabs`: `"acct_id"`.
Use `F(x)` to declare that a continuous variable `x` is to be treated as a factor.

> Error in rxCall("RxCrossTabs", params) :
>   Calls: rxCube -> rxCubeBase -> rxCall -> .Call

Comment: There is a dedicated CRAN Task View: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `acct_id` was treated as `numeric` when you imported and it needs to be a `factor`.

You have three options:
1. Import again and use the `colClasses = c(acct_id = "factor")`.
2. Use `rxFactors` to change `acct_id` to a `factor`.
3. Change to a `factor` in the formula.

```r
acct_avg_rank <- rxCube(N(m13_rank) ~ F(acct_id), data=payee_merge,
                        means=TRUE, returnDataFrame=TRUE)
```